# How to fix HTML layout issues in an NSTextView on macOS Sonoma?

Tags: swift, macos, webkit, nstextview, textkit

On macOS Sonoma (23A5312d) there are HTML table layout issues when using an `NSAttributedString` in an `NSTextView`.

Consider the following Swift code:

```swift
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let html = """
<table width="100%" border="1" style="color: white">
  <tr>
    <td align="left">Left</td>
    <td align="right">Right</td>
  </tr>
</table>
"""
        let data = Data(html.utf8)
        let definition = try! NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, .characterEncoding: NSNumber(value: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)], documentAttributes: nil)
        let frameRect = NSRect(x: 100, y: 0, width: 300, height: 200)
        let textView = NSTextView(frame: frameRect)
        textView.textStorage?.setAttributedString(definition)
        textView.backgroundColor = .clear

        view.addSubview(textView)
    }
```

On macOS Ventura, it appears like this:

[image]

On macOS Sonoma, it appears like this:

[image]

On mouse over, the HTML (albeit broken) appears:

[image]

This was reported to Apple as FB12800496, and they responded outlining that it was due to "downgrading to TextKit 1 for handling the table contents". They recommended using "TextKit1 NSTextView via init(usingTextLayoutManager:)", the following code resolves the issue of the HTML initially not appearing:

```swift
let textView = NSTextView(usingTextLayoutManager: false)
textView.frame = frameRect
```

Apple Feedback wrote that the layout issue is from "WebKit’s NSAttributedString translation" and that it's handled properly for "TextKit’s internal WebKit1 translator".

Is it possible to invoke the "WebKit1 translator"?

**Update 2023-11-01**

Following the "Opt out programmatically" instructions in Apple's [What's new in TextKit and text views](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/10090/?time=625) developer video to force TextKit 1 resulted in different layout issues:
[image]

Comment: I think your code transforms tables into `NSTextTable`, which isn't supported by TextKit 2. Compatibility between TextKit 1/2 is very flimsy and unreliable, and you might be better off changing the whole text view to TextKit 1 mode.

Comment: Isn't `NSTextView(usingTextLayoutManager: false)` supposed to opt out of TextKit 2?

Comment: I updated the question to include the TextKit 1 result when using an `NSTextContainer`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that only Apple can fix this, macOS 14.2 (23C64) fixes some TextKit issues but this example now looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Fixed in macOS 14.3 (23D56).